# WHERE Statement on a Recursive CTE Query To Get All Parents of a Child Node

Tags: mysql, sql, common-table-expression

I have the following data set, which basically is a tree from which all nodes belong:

```
name         |id   |parent_id
Planet Earth |1    |0
North America|2    |1
Costa Rica   |46408|2
Alajuela     |46409|46408
Cartago      |46410|46408
Guanacaste   |46411|46408
Heredia      |46412|46408
...
```

I want to be able to query to get all of the bottom nodes in the tree, the below query works perfectly for this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM locations l 
WHERE l.id NOT IN (SELECT parent_id FROM locations)
AND l.name LIKE ?
```

I want to output the data in the following format:

**query**

```
SELECT * 
FROM locations l 
WHERE l.id NOT IN (SELECT parent_id FROM locations)
AND l.name LIKE 'he%'
SPOOKY SQL MAGIC GOES HERE...
```

**Output**

```
name   |id   |parent_id|parents
Heredia|46412|46408    |Planet Earth > North America > Costa Rica
```

I've started to work on the query myself something like the below:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT id, parent_id, name, CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),name) AS parents
        FROM locations
        WHERE idParent = 0
    UNION ALL
        SELECT l.id, l.parent_id, l.name,  c.parents + ' > ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),t.name) AS parents
        FROM locations l
        INNER JOIN CTE c ON l.idParent = c.id
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

As you can see I'm using recursion with Common Table Expressions, but I can't figure out how to combine the two queries. Also the above query runs on the entire table.

- How can I limit the above CTE query to a subset of the table?
- How do I achieve my desired output?

Comment: Try [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7u35kLbJ5jWLECLZoavGww/2).

Comment: Thank you. How could this be achieved with MySQL 5.7? The production db uses 5.7.

Comment: CTEs are supported from MySQL 8.0.1. In previous versions it's possible but less easy to achieve the same result. See [WITH RECURSIVE and MySQL](http://guilhembichot.blogspot.com/2013/11/with-recursive-and-mysql.html).

Comment: Ok, thank you. Please post your comment as an answer and I will accept it. Your initial comment was actually the answer to my post, I didn't say any thing about 5.7 so by rights you've answered what I asked.